# How to get Y value from exponential function that starts at 0,0 and ends at 100,1000

Tags: javascript, function, math, graph, linear-algebra

It's been a while since my math classes so here's the question, any help is appreciated.

I'll be implementing the function in javascript also.

I have an X range of 0-100 and a set max Y of 10000 (which may change).
This is an exponential function and the closer X is to 100, the closer it gets to  Y max and x=100 is y=10000. So my question is, what is the function that can handle this? Ideally I'd like to have something to control the steepness of the curve as well.

What I have in mind : 
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLifD.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to know how to get the Y value in javascript?

Comment: Yeah, or just the expression, I can manage putting it in js from there. Whatever is easiest for you.

Comment: Because otherwise, this question should be asked on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well it will be used in javascript

Comment: Programming goes hand to wand with maths, thus this is really just a math question... this indeed should be asked on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [read this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingExponential.html), see if its what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula would be a variant of y = a * exp(b * x), where you can play around with a and b to get the curve / endpoints you want. For 100/100.000, you could use:
y = 5 * exp(0.0990348754944493 * x). In Javascript that would look something like:

```
function getExponent(x) {
   return 5 * Math.pow(0.0990348754944493*x);
}
```

or if you want a and b to be variables:

```
function getExponent(x,a,b) {
   return a * Math.pow(b*x);
}
```

Comment: I want to be able to provide x and the y value at x=100. I can't go in the code and edit the floats every time I have a different y max. 

For example, what is Y when X = 56 when the exponential starts at (0,0) and intercepts with the point (100,10000)?

The range of 0-100 will never change, the steepness I will play with but eventually will be static and the "max" Y value will vary. Think of it like a slider, you slide it up to the max which in this case is 10000. But some sliders go up to 100000 or a million, etc.

Comment: If you want to make the steepness static, we can assume b is (becomes) fixed. Since y_max and x_max are known (although y_max is varying), you can use a function to calculate a:
a = exp(b * x_max) / y_max = exp(b * 100) / y_max
Then... whenever you have fixed b, the interceptions (0,0) and (100, y_max) will always hold.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense but Math.pow() requires two args, and exp() doesn't exist in my environment. I did try Math.exp(b * x_max) / y_max but that returns an 18 digit number.

Comment: Ah yes, my b was incorrect. Changed it to 0.0990348754944493, that results exactly in y = 100.000 for x = 100 and a = 5